# Retrieve comments Facebook users make as the Like a web page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I've been pouring over Facebook's Graph API but I can't seem to find any documentation with regards to retrieve comments users leave as they Like an Open Graph object (in my case, a web page with a Like button).

At a minimum, I would assume that there would be some way to retrieve comments from users whose privacy settings allow anybody to see their updates (I guess this might require me to know the UID of everybody who Likes my web page). Alternatively, there might be some method where user comments may be associated with the Open Graph object's stream instead.

Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

To see a user's wall feed via the API (even public ones) you will to have them authenticate your app.  Yeah, pretty crappy not to be able to query their public messages, but it is a current limitation of Facebook's API.